# Why use hashed CSS stylesheet and Javascript file names?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, hash

When looking deeply at the code of some most popular websites, I've seen many times that, CSS and JavaScript file name are like this,

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//sample.com/css/css__k3sYInttBtNNuJgtPSyqaYy9vVxS4qTZLrfs1ujQB9g__SH_QaIH3bnSp3nOw8n8afhszfHJlxVt51qRlrrrOnk0__fBOuweRojwN82z7EY4v-sVsMwU_P_vZSaU3fmyho6Do.css" media="all" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="//sample.com/js/js__-V23Vc4PVahQcqfyxss_rmNogErBARnPCvI7oPXC0qQ__O-yO5Gg8pRRaefl4d0X9qXUJTOSHq0yazxF-4tJCU_k__fBOuweRojwN82z7EY4v-sVsMwU_P_vZSaU3fmyho6Do.js"></script>
```

It seems like that file names has been hashed and I don't know what is the reason. So I've got following problems.

1. What is the **purpose** of using this kind of method?
2. I've seen **Very complex folder names** also. Why is that?
3. Are there any security concerns?
4. Can we **dynamically change file/folder names** using PHP for maximum security?

I am little new to this area.

Comment: If bundle would be rebuilt, hash changes and browser knows that it needed to update cached assets

Comment: The names are generated through automation scripts. It prevents name collisions and stops browser caching issues.

Comment: ^^ That.  They're generated, probably during bundling.

Comment: @MysterX that will also work if you add versions like `http://wxample.com/.../abc.js?v=0.5.3` won't it ?

Comment: Yes, most modern browsers will be just fine with this syntax, but years ago some older versions of browsers would go by file name only for caching purposes. Also when developing your version number does not change and you may be testing a page with the same css  or js file many hundreds of times, so rather than worrying about version number (whcih does not change on your dev environment) it may be easier to include date or a timestamp instead, or a hash...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can assume that these file/folder names are not what the developers are working with during the development phase, but rather **an artifact of the files' build process**. JavaScript and CSS is often built into a single file from several source files, involving more or less compilation/transpilation and bundling steps.

The reason why you would want the filename to be/include a hash of the file is that this **forces a cache invalidation whenever the file changes**. Static files can be cached by the browser, server, and a number of other agents in-between. This is fine as long as the file does not change. However, when a new release is published, the user should be served this new version. If the file name of the resource changes, the browser will always request the new version of the file from the server, rather than using a cached version.

You should **not rely on complex file names like this as a security/authorization feature**. The file names are referenced in the app's index file and thus known to the end user. Also, security by obscurity is generally a bad idea.

Comment: will it not work if you add versions like `http://wxample.com/.../abc.js?v=0.5.3` ?? the browser takes the complete url along with any params (if present), doesn't it ?

Comment: @mrid Yep, that would also do the trick. But there is really no incentive to keep the file names human-readable, since in a well set-up build/deployment process, no human will ever touch them. Also, this approach requires the developer to maintain some kind of versioning scheme, while a file hash can be calculated fully automatically.